# Connect ruby to sql server 2012 express

Tags: ruby, sql-server

I'd like to connect ruby to sql server 2012 express. After researching, I've come up with this article. The only problem is that [the article](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sql_server/0.1.1/frames) dates from 2010. Is there any new article that explain how to do the connection. Is it so hard to find one that is recent. I just need to be able to connect to Sql Server 2012. Both ruby and Sql Server 2012 Express are on my laptop which run windows 7.

Comment: Did you try at all? If so, what problems did you face?

Comment: have you looked at the tidy_tds gem? i used it recently https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Ruby On Rails you shoudl have a look at the ActiveRecord SqlServer Adapter

- https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.

It uses TinyTDS as its low loevel connection adapter. But you may also use TinyTDS standalone

- https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds.

Both are well tested and documented. I use them in our production environment.

Comment: Sorry, it took me forever to get back to you. I've just downloaded tiny_tds. Now I'm struggling with the notion of gem installation. the following command $ gem install tiny_tds is supposed to install the gem. I'm getting the following error: undefined local variable or method "tiny_tds".

Comment: On what system are you trying to install it?
Are you able to install other gems ?